# Custom event not listened by parent window from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to listen a custom event triggered from the iframe in parent window. I tried to bind event even on document and window but not succeed.

Main JS:

```
$(document).bind('EVENT_ANIMATION_COMPLETE', onAnimationComplete);
```

JS using in iframe:

```
$(document).trigger('EVENT_ANIMATION_COMPLETE');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `document` in the iframe is not equal to the `document` in the parent.

There are a couple of ways to do it, one way is

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger("EVENT_ANIMATION_COMPLETE");
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks @epascarello , its working now! Hat's off to you.